# Why is my element no longer hidden after the animation is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

What I'm trying to accomplish is a grid of boxes, where each box animates when clickde, then shows a corresponding detail view that covers the entire grid.

The detail view includes a link to return back to the grid view.

In my full implementation, there will be carousel-style navigation from detail view to detail view, with animations.  Because of this, I want to hide the grid of boxes with a simple overlay, which should revert to hidden once the user returns to the grid view.

The problem is that the JQuery `hide()` call seems to be removed when the animation completes... sometimes, but not always.

I've created [a simple JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg62qxsj/) showing the behavior I'm trying to avoid.  When you click on one of the boxes, the next `.expanded-card` element displays properly.  When you click on "back to overview", the `.expanded-card` element fades out appropriately, and the `.grid-background` overlay is hidden.

But as soon as the `zoomOut` animation completes, `.grid-background` becomes visible again.  Why?

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row grid-3x3-container">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                <div class="container-fluid grid-3x3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 grid-item">
                            <div class="flip-box animated">
                                <h3>Title 1</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="expanded-card animated col-xs-12">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <span class="card-nav-back"> back to overview</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <p>
                                Text goes here!
                              </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 grid-item">
                            <div class="flip-box animated">
                                <h3>Title 2</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="expanded-card animated col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <div class="card-header ">
                                <span class="card-nav-back"> back to overview</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <p>
                                Text goes here!
                              </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 grid-item">
                            <div class="flip-box animated">
                                <h3>Title 3</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="expanded-card animated col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <div class="card-header ">
                                <span class="card-nav-back"> back to overview</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <p>
                                Text goes here!
                              </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 grid-background">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
  $('.flip-box').on("click", function () {
        var currentCard = $(this).parent();
        currentCard.addClass('current-selection');
        var expandedCard = currentCard.next('.expanded-card');
        currentCard.addClass('flipOutX');
        currentCard.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
          expandedCard.show();
          expandedCard.addClass('zoomIn');
          currentCard.find('h3').show();
          expandedCard.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
            expandedCard.removeClass('zoomIn');
            $('.grid-background').show();
          });
        });
    });
    $('.expanded-card').on("click", '.card-header>.card-nav-back', function () {
        var currentGridItem = $('.current-selection');
        var currentCard = currentGridItem.next('.expanded-card');
        currentGridItem.removeClass('current-selection');
        currentCard.addClass('zoomOut');
        currentCard.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
          currentCard.removeClass('zoomOut');
          currentCard.hide();
        });
        $('.grid-background').hide();
    });
```

Comment: There isn't anything in this code snippet that relates to `.grid-overlay`; where is that?

Comment: I think that was a typo, he meant `.grid-background`.

Comment: @xCRKxTyPHooN Barmar is correct; that was a typo (now fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
        expandedCard.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
          expandedCard.removeClass('zoomIn');
          $('.grid-background').show();
        });
```

[corrected fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dg62qxsj/2/)

You had `.on` instead of `.one`, so the later "zoomOut" animation would trigger this again, so it would show `.grid-background`.

Maybe it was just a typo, because you got it right in code for clicking on `.expanded-card`.

Another possibility, instead of binding a handler each time, is to delegate the handlers to the `.zoomIn` and `.zoomOut` classes.

```
$(".container").on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", ".zoomIn", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("zoomIn");
  $(".grid-background").show();
});

$(".container").on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", ".zoomOut", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("zoomOut").hide();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dg62qxsj/6/)

Comment: /facepalm  Yep, that was it!  I'm using `on()` for some of the event handlers, but that should definitely be `one()`.  Thanks!

Comment: Good rule of thumb: binding one event handler inside another event handler is usually wrong.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I've got some more refactoring to do.  I can see how I should restructure the animation end bindings to be specific to the element, rather than the calling event.

Comment: @Beofett You might also be able to do it using event delegation, see my updated answer.

Comment: Still working on cleanup up my code, but delegating the handlers to the animation classes is a tremendous improvement.  So much cleaner....